# Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions, may take a while STS?

Tags: eclipse, installation, spring-tool-suite

I would like to ask what does this error mean when adding a new `Available Software Site` and installing new software in Eclipse/STS (Spring Tool Suite) using `Install New Software`?

I am experiencing this problem with the `Spring Tool Suite Nightly Build`:

http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS/nightly-distributions.html

I am trying to update my STS and reinstall the `Welcome Dashboard`. When I try to add the following `Available Software Site`:

`http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/nightly/e4.5`

I select all the items in order that they all will be installed,

Then this message is shown in the progress indicator:

> Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions, may take a while.

Sometimes I get this message even when trying to update something.

What does it mean? That I have some items already installed? That there's a problem contacting the site?

Comment: the best way is to make a new clean instance of Eclipse and open the existing workspace you are working on, because it will take too much time sometimes to finish

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Means that plugins that you have are conflicting with the ones attempted to be installed. Once it computes the alternate paths, it pops up the next wizard page. you should be able to see what the conflicts are.
In this particular case it might be something related to Groovy Eclipse. Try not selecting Groovy and Grails and see if that helps.

Comment: Use a new/clean instance of Eclipse IDE, then install plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the similar issue while installing TestNg plugin from eclipse marketplace. I resolved this issue by following steps:

1. Select marketplace from help section.
2. Search TestNG plugin.
3. Click on install button.
4. When you see the error message 'can not perform operation computing alternate solutions'.
5. Do not stop the installation from computing alternate solution.
6. At the end you will see a window 'The Installation can not be completed as requested'.
7. On this window select 'Show original error' radio button.
8. Now select an older version of software and click on 'Confirm' button to install.

Comment: This worked for me for TestNG on eclipse-oxygen