# How to Install JBoss Tools 4.1.2 on Eclipse Kepler OFFLINE

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss-tools

What im trying to do is install JBOSS Tools onto Eclipse Keplar OFFLINE. The reason i'm trying to do an offline installation is that i'm working on a VM that does and cannot have internet access.

So first i must ask is this at all anyway possible?

I have downloaded the zips from the JBoss Tools download site and use the Eclipse archive installer but it always goes to "Cannot perform operation. Computing alternative solutions". What it looks like it's doing at this point is access online directories which it cannot do. I've tried doing this with just the Abridged JBoss Tools as that's the minimum requirements i need but it does the same thing.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what is it showing if you let compute alternative solutions and choose "make your own - see original error" ?

Answer (score 2):

First you need [Eclipse Kepler for Java EE Developers](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr2), then you need [JBoss Tools 4.1.2.Final p2 repository for Eclipse Kepler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/JBossTools/JBossTools4.1.x/jbosstools-Update-4.1.2.Final_2014-03-18_15-46-19-B706.zip), then just do it the same way as you did before and it should work this time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is the "JBossTools Update" zip folder which is the first thing i tried, unfortunately does that same thing. It looks like while its computing the alternative solutions its trying to download a context.jar and context.xml file which is in this zip. Is there any settings i can change to tell it to look in the archive or is this normal?

Comment: Combination of Kepler for Java EE Developers and JBoss Tools Update has everything to install offline. I am sorry you have this problem, but I tested it myself and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

i read in other post of stackoverflow  when the comes the error:

> Cannot perform operation. Computing alternative solutions.

Means that plugins that you have are conflicting with the ones attempted to be installed.Once it computes the alternate paths and next wizrd page is presented you should be able to see what the conflicts are. In this particular case it might be something related to MAven Profiles Management..

link referenced: [Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions, may take a while STS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983382/cannot-perform-operation-computing-alternate-solutions-may-take-a-while-sts)

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting an answer. Please improve your answer by linking to the other posts that you mention. Your post could also be improved by fixing small spelling and syntax mistakes (e.g., spaces next to periods) that detract from your answer.